Partial standard basis measurement of a three element system
I'm trying to solve a textbook problem.
There are three elements in the system. The system is in the state
$$\psi=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\big(|0\rangle|+\rangle|-\rangle + |1\rangle|0\rangle|0\rangle - |1\rangle|1\rangle|1\rangle\big).$$
A standard basis measurement is performed on the middle element. What is the probability  that the measurement results in the outcome 0. What is the state of the three elements conditioned on getting the outcome 0 for the measurement.
First, I rearrange the elements into ones that are measured (2) and the ones that are not (1 and 3). That is:
\begin{align}
\psi&=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\big(|+\rangle_2|0\rangle_1|-\rangle_3 + |0\rangle_2|1\rangle_1|0\rangle_3 - |1\rangle_2|1\rangle_1|1\rangle_3\big)\\
&=|+\rangle_2\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt3}|0\rangle_1|-\rangle_3\bigg) + |0\rangle_2\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt3}|1\rangle_1|0\rangle_3\bigg) - |1\rangle_2\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt3}|1\rangle_1|1\rangle_3\bigg)
\end{align}
So, the probability is $(1/\sqrt3)^2=1/3$ and the state is
$$|0\rangle_2\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt3}|1\rangle_1|0\rangle_3\bigg)\Big/\frac{1}{\sqrt3}=|0\rangle_2|1\rangle_1|0\rangle_3=|1\rangle|0\rangle|0\rangle.$$
However, this is not indicated as the right answer. Where is my mistake?

The question asks the probability of outcome 0 on the second register when measuring in the computation basis. The computation basis is $\{|0\rangle, |1\rangle\}$. This means you first need to rewrite the state in a computation basis. Specifically, you must express $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$ is the computation basis and multiplying everything out. At the end you will get a state that will have the following form:
$$\sum_{i=0}^1\sum_{j=0}^1\sum_{k=0}^1a_{ijk}|i\rangle|j\rangle|k\rangle,$$
where $a_{ijk}$ are probability amplitudes and $i,j,k \in \{0,1\}$.
Next, you look at the terms of the form $a_{i0k}|i\rangle|0\rangle|k\rangle$. The probability of measuring 0 in the second register is then given by
$$\sum_{i=1}^1\sum_{k=0}^1 |a_{i0k}|^2.$$
In other words, you sum squared amplitudes of all terms with $|0\rangle$ in the second register.
For example, if you had a state
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(|0\rangle|0\rangle|1\rangle + |1\rangle|0\rangle|1\rangle + |1\rangle|1\rangle|1\rangle \right ) \tag{1}$$
then the probability of measuring 0 (according to what I wrote above) in the second register is 1/3 + 1/3 = 2/3. And the probability of measuring 1 in the third register is 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 = 1. This is because we clearly see that the third register is not in a superposition cause we could rewrite the state above as:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(|0\rangle|0\rangle + |1\rangle|0\rangle + |1\rangle |1\rangle \right )\otimes|1\rangle.$$
For the second part. Consider again the state in  (1). Suppose you measured 0 in the second register. Then we know that whatever terms contained 0 in the second register must have "survived" the measurement process. So we get:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|0\rangle|0\rangle|1\rangle + |1\rangle|0\rangle|1\rangle \right).$$
We see that after the measurement on the second register, the second register collapsed to 0. Mathematically speaking, we performed a projection operation on (1). The projector is $I \otimes |0\rangle \langle 0| \otimes I$. After performing the projection operation, we need to normalize the state to have norm 1.
So, now apply all these to your state.

I thought that the states $+$ and $-$ are some arbitrary states (a set of states is ${0, 1, +, -}$) and not $|+\rangle=(|0\rangle)+|1\rangle)/\sqrt2$.
